# Overriding Material2 Style with Custom CSS

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have Datepicker element in Angular. It is standard component from Material Design.

When I try to set own styles to this element, it does not work with property `!important`.

How to fix it, and how to change the default component's styles?

Example of code:

```
.mat-datepicker-toggle {
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding this style? in component or app css?

Comment: In `main.css` I tried everywhere

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/E9JNhFsKv7yBZowYhwIl?p=preview look at this plunker. it's work with component, `datepicker-overview-example.css`

Comment: one more thing you can try with `/deep/ .mat-datepicker-toggle {
  margin-right: 10px !important;
  border: 1px solid red;
}` use `/deep/` before `.mat-datepicker-toggle`

Comment: I set CSS styles in component where I use this element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to set the [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) to None on your component:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './my.component.html' ,
    styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss'], //or .css, depending what you use
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Then in your component css you can do exactly what you tried:

```
.mat-datepicker-toggle {
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: I hide navbar for login page but when I return to home via the router, navbar also gets hide for the home page until I refresh the page.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `::ng-deep`. In your component css, set your style to the following:

> ```
> ::ng-deep .mat-datepicker-toggle {
>   margin-right: 10px !important;
> }
> ```

Comment: This works, but it is currently deprecated. https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep