# Change radio button color in Material 2 with plain CSS

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have problems changing the color of the radio button of the Angular Material 2 component. I searched through other answers and couldn't make it work.

Here is a plunkr from the Material 2 radio-button example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/JNDRKkF2oAxU5gPsR4lO?p=preview

I know that it would work with this line

```
<md-radio-button color="primary" class="example-radio-button"
   *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">
    {{season}}
</md-radio-button>
```

But I cannot use the "color" property because we are using an older version of Material 2 and we cannot upgrade it currently.

So anybody know how to do it with plain CSS in the above example I would be very grateful. I tried it for over an hour now..

Comment: What you mean cannot use 'color', in the css?

Comment: the color="primary" attribute on the md-radio-button

Comment: Check out my answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45615449/6139866)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your angular version is 2.4.3, my assumption is you are using beta.2 or older version of material (beta.3 and later requires angular 4.x). The classes in older versions have different class names than current one. So, you can try following css:

Material beta.1:

```
/deep/ .md-radio-inner-circle {
    background-color: skyblue;  /* Pick your color */
}

/deep/ .md-radio-checked .md-radio-outer-circle {
    border-color: skyblue;     /* Pick your color */
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/YBOfcn9qmvOf5GXqX8M7?p=preview) using Angular 2.4.1 and Material beta.1

Material beta.2:

```
/deep/ .mat-radio-inner-circle {
    background-color: yellow;
}

/deep/ .mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle {
    border-color: lime;
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/XAW6aXnRoJQnKMCL5wSU?p=info) using Angular 2.4.1 and Material beta.2

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `::ng-deep`. Add the following classes to you component style:

```
/deep/  .mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle{
    border-color: green;
}

/deep/  .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle{
    background-color: green;
}
```

See this [**PLUNKER DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/kZuhsGAWwZjP0oV8oWee?p=preview)

Comment: our application still runs with angular 2.4.3 so I cannot use this feature

Comment: is `/deep/` similar to `::ng-deep`?

Comment: with 2.4.3, use `/deep/` ... see the updated answer, plunker also updated.

Comment: unfortunately this solution is not working in our application. but thank you for your effort. we will keep it in the accent color for now and fix it when we update our Angular and Material 2 versions.

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: no sorry, will take me too much time and it is just a really small part of our application. i was just wondering why i couldn't override the css classes of the md-component in this exact case.